# Integration identity

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $f:[a,b]\to V$ be a Hilbert valued function which is $L^2$. By expanding the norm in terms of the inner product, I got the following identity. Is it true?

$\Vert \int_a^b f(s) ds\Vert^2=(b-a) \int_a^b \Vert f(s)\Vert^2 ds.$

Here is the calculation:
\begin{align*}
\Vert \int_a^b f(s) ds\Vert^2 &= \langle \int_a^b f(s) ds, \int_a^b f(s) ds\rangle \\
& = \int_a^b (\langle f(s), \int_a^b f(s) ds\rangle)ds\\
& = \int_a^b (\int_a^b \langle f(s), f(s)\rangle ds)ds\\
& =(b-a) \int_a^b \Vert f(s)\Vert^2 ds.
\end{align*}
Where is the mistake?

Comment: Let $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$. Does $f$ satisfy the identity?

Comment: @SamuelM.A.Luque see my update.

Comment: You cannot use the same variable of integration $s$ for the two integrals. Use different variables and you will see that this calculatioin does not work.

Comment: @geetha290krm why we cannot?

Comment: Your third equality is not valid if you use the same $s$.

Comment: @Migalobe ... "Why we cannot?"  Take the Samuel example, plug into the formulas, see which of the steps is wrong.

Comment: I wa talking about "You cannot use the same variable of integration s for the two integrals." Of course we can, but we cannot change the integral with the inner product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Vert \int_a^b f(s) ds\Vert^2 = \langle \int_a^b f(s) ds, \int_a^b f(t) dt\rangle \\
 = \int_a^b (\langle f(s), \int_a^b f(t) dt\rangle)ds\\
= \int_a^b (\int_a^b \langle f(s), f(t)\rangle dt)ds\\$.

Further simplification is not possible.